# conditional expectation with uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

If $r$ follows a uniform distribution on $[-10,20]$, what is the conditional expectation of $E[r|r<0]$? I feel very confused dealing with the $r<0$ condition.
This comes from a question where I am asked to compute $E[r|r<0]*P(r<0)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given $r \lt 0$, it is conditionally uniformly distributed on $[-10,0)$

Comment: Can you write the exact formula? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If $r$ follows a uniform distribution on $[−10;20]$, what is the conditional expectation of $E[r|r<0]$?

It is just the expected value of $r$ where it is less than $0$ , divided by the probability that it is less than $0$.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(r\mid r<0) &= \dfrac{\mathsf E(r~\mathbf 1_{r<0})}{\mathsf P(r<0)} \\[1ex]&= \dfrac{\int_{-10}^0 r~f(r)\operatorname d r}{\int_{-10}^0 f(r)\operatorname d x} \\[1ex]&= \int_{-10}^{0}r~f(r\mid r< 0)\operatorname d r\end{align}$$

Now, since $r$ is uniformly distributed over $[-10;20]$, then ...

---

PS:

> This comes from a question where I am asked to compute $E[r|r<0]∗P(r<0) $

Of course, that is just $\mathsf E(r~\mathbf 1_{r<0}) = \int_{-10}^0 r~f(r)\operatorname d r$

PPS: $\mathbf 1_{r<0}$ is an Indicator function; a piecewise function that is $1$ only where indicated, and $0$ elsewhere. $$\mathbf 1_{r<0}~=~\begin{cases}1&:& r<0\\ 0& :&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you explain how to write the conditional pdf when we are conditioning on some inequality? Just as this question, I intend to write a exact formula for $f(r|r< 0)$, but dealing with the inequality makes me very uncomfortable.

Comment: It is just: $$f(r\mid r<0) ~=~ \dfrac{f(r)~\mathbf 1_{r<0}}{\int_\Bbb R f(\rho)\mathbf 1_{\rho<0}\operatorname d \rho}\qquad=~\dfrac{f(r)~\mathbf 1_{r<0}}{\int_{-10}^0 f(\rho)\operatorname d \rho}$$

Comment: So you mean $r$, not $\rho$ in the denominator, right?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  Recall that the token for the variable of integration may be alpha-replaced by any free token. $\int f(\rho)\operatorname d \rho = \int f(r)\operatorname d r = \int f(z)\operatorname d z = \int f(\heartsuit)\operatorname d \heartsuit$ As a matter of style, I prefer to use a token distinct from anything used outside of an integral's scope, is all.